# Tables in visualforce page renderAs Pdf are moving to the top of the page

Tags: visualforce, pdf, getcontentaspdf, flying-saucer

I am rendering a html code as pdf in visualforce page. But the tables in the page are going to the TOP. If I remove renderAs="pdf" and check the VF page, everything looks fine. Please advice. Thank you.

VF code:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountStatementVFController" renderAs="PDF">
<html>
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div style="width: 50%;float: left">
            <div style="width: 60%;font-weight: bold">
                Account info here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 40%;float: right">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
                <tr> all td comes here </td>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%;float: left;clear: both">
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;-Fs-table-paginate: paginate">
                <tr> All td lines comes here</tr>
            </table>
        </div>
         <div style="width: 100%;float: left">
            <hr/>
        </div>
        Another table below
    </div>
</html>
```

</apex:page>

ScreenShot:
[image]

As you can see, The table is just merging to the top. Please check the expected screenshot which I am able to get if I remove renderAs="pdf".

EXPECTED page in the PDF Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: See [flying-saucer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying-saucer) posts. The PDF generation in Salesforce does not support some of the more modern parts of CSS.

Comment: Could you please suggest me any workarounds on getting this look. Thank you.